# Previnir undefined de elementos que pode ou não aparecer no documento

Tags: javascript

O JS DOM abaixo é para modificar através das classes, o estilos de dois elementos que sãos criados dinamicamente no documento. Mas não é sempre que esses elementos aparecerão no documento. Talvez eles apareçam, talvez não. Quando eles estão, o código funciona bem, e quando não estão, o console retorna `TypeError: jsNavButton is undefined`. Como fazer para evitar isso?

`var jsNavButton = document.querySelectorAll(".js-nav-toggle")[0],
jsNavHidden = document.querySelectorAll(".js-nav-hidden")[0];
jsNavButton.style.backgroundColor = "tomato";
jsNavHidden.style.backgroundColor = "blue";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verifique se os elementos existem com `if`. Se o elemento não existir, nada é feito e não retorna erro:

```
var jsNavButton = document.querySelectorAll(".js-nav-toggle")[0],
   jsNavHidden = document.querySelectorAll(".js-nav-hidden")[0];

if(jsNavButton){
   jsNavButton.style.backgroundColor = "tomato";
}

if(jsNavHidden){
   jsNavHidden.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

Comment: Funcional como sempre. Thx.